# How to avoid jsx styling error in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Whenever I tried to build UI from scratch I'm getting this error `adjacent jsx element must be wrapped in an enclosing tag`. I don't know how to solve this. Because I tried different methods, I've tried to put the blocks within `View` component with`flex:1` but non-use. Is there any proper solution for this. This is becoming a great challenge for me because I can't design any components of my own. What to do please help me. Following is my code.

**screen.js**

```
   export default  class FirstScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
 showPopupDialog: false,
 workType: "",
 workers: []
}
}
      componentWillMount(){
            fetch('http://192.168.1.6:3000/api/worker', {
              method:'GET',
              headers:{
                Accept: 'application/json'
              }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseData =>
              this.setState({
              workers:responseData
              })
            )
      }
      onPressYes = (workType) => {
       console.log(workType);
      }

popupDialog = (id, workType) => {
  this.setState ({
     showPopupDialog: true,
     workType: workType
  });
  //make sure you set showPopupDialog to false and workType to "" when you click yes or no button in PopupDialog component so that it will work the next time you click on card
}
render() {
    const { workers, workType, showPopupDialog} = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <Header />
             <ScrollView>
                {workers.map((a, index)=> (
                   <View style={{flex:1}}>
                      <CardSection>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.popupDialog(a.id, a.work_type)}>
                          <View style={{ maringTop: 10, marginLeft:120}}>
                            <Image style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} source={{ uri: a.work_type == 'Carpenter' ? images[0].image : images[1].image}}/>
                            <Text style={{marginLeft:20, fontSize:20}}>{a.work_type}</Text>
                          </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                      </CardSection>
                      </View>
                  ))}
                  {showPopupDialog && <PopupDialog
                        dialogStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", height: 180, width:300, borderWidth:1,padding:10}}
                        overlayBackgroundColor="#fff" dismissOnTouchOutside={true}>
                          <View style={styles.dialogContentView}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:18, margingTop:10,color:"#000000"}}>Are you sure you want to submit?</Text>
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                              <View style={styles.button_1}>
                                <Button title="Yes" color="#FF6633" onPress={() => this.onPressYes(workType)}/>
                              </View>
                              <View style={styles.button_1}>
                                <Button title="No" color="#FF6633" onPress={() =>this._onPressNo() }/>
                              </View>
                            </View>
                          </View>
                        </PopupDialog>}
                </ScrollView>
              </View>
            );
          }
        }
```

The issue I'm facing is I can't place the `<PopupDialog>` component adjacent to `<CardSection>` , in order to that I put the `<PopupDialog>` within `<View>` ,even though it doesn't solve my issue.Please help..Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try with below corrected code.

There are two things that needs be corrected

> 1. You are doing .map but you are not returning anything which I have
>      corrected in the code below

```
export default  class FirstScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
 workType: "",
 workers: []
}
}
      componentWillMount(){
            fetch('http://192.168.1.6:3000/api/worker', {
              method:'GET',
              headers:{
                Accept: 'application/json'
              }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseData =>
              this.setState({
              workers:responseData
              })
            )
      }
      onPressYes = (workType) => {
       console.log(workType);
      }

popUpDialog = (id, workType) => {
  this.setState ({
     workType: workType
  });
  this.popupDialog.show();

  //make sure you set workType to "" when you click yes or no button in PopupDialog component so that it will work the next time you click on card
}
render() {
    const { workers, workType} = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <Header />
             <ScrollView>
                {workers.map((a, index)=> (
                   <View style={{flex:1}}>
                      <CardSection>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.popUpDialog(a.id, a.work_type)}>
                          <View style={{ maringTop: 10, marginLeft:120}}>
                            <Image style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} source={{ uri: a.work_type == 'Carpenter' ? images[0].image : images[1].image}}/>
                            <Text style={{marginLeft:20, fontSize:20}}>{a.work_type}</Text>
                          </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                      </CardSection>
                      </View>
                  ))}
                  <PopupDialog ref={popupDialog => {
                           this.popupDialog = popupDialog;
                         }}
                        dialogStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", height: 180, width:300, borderWidth:1,padding:10}}
                        overlayBackgroundColor="#fff" dismissOnTouchOutside={true}>
                          <View style={styles.dialogContentView}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:18, margingTop:10,color:"#000000"}}>Are you sure you want to submit?</Text>
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                              <View style={styles.button_1}>
                                <Button title="Yes" color="#FF6633" onPress={() => this.onPressYes(workType)}/>
                              </View>
                              <View style={styles.button_1}>
                                <Button title="No" color="#FF6633" onPress={() =>this._onPressNo() }/>
                              </View>
                            </View>
                          </View>
                        </PopupDialog>
                </ScrollView>
              </View>
            );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly...
You can return multiple root elements in jsx by wrapping is in a [`<React.Fragment>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactfragment) element (you can use `<>` and `</>` in v16.2 and later). Fragments are new in React v16. Prior to that, you just have to wrap them in some element (a `div` or `span`, usually).

Comment: So can I use this as a react native `component` ?Instead of using `View` component?

Comment: Her code is more of react-native. How does div or span helps here?

Comment: @anu it's basically a View component that's not rendered with any styles (not really but you can think of it like that)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have this structure:

```
<a>
  {this.state.workers.map((a, index)=>
    <b/>
    <c/>
  )}
</a>
```

Since `<b/><c/>` is parsed separately and there's no enclosing element, you're getting the error. But an enclosing element isn't necessary for the final structure, which *does* have an enclosing element. The solution is to simply return an array of JSX elements, like this:

```
<a>
  {this.state.workers.map((a, index)=>
    [<b/>,
     <c/>]
  )}
</a>
```

Comment: You answer is same as what I answered before you 19 mins ago. Did I down vote your answer? No.

Comment: @Think-Twice I'm using an *Array*, not an additional View. And I've explained the reason for my downvote multiple times now.

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry I do not have time to explain or argue with you